# Regex to parse percentage from the string

Tags: python, regex, percentage

I want to get all the percentage from above string with decimal or without decimal points.
I also want to get % sign.

```
string  = """Bachelor of Engineering in Electronics from  in 2013 with 60%.
Diploma (Electronics & Video Engineering) from  in 2009 with 79.39%.
SSC from  in 2006 with 61.71%."""
```

I have tried as below

```
re.findall(r'\d+%|([0-9]\d?)\.\d+%', string)
```

getting output as

```
['', '79', '61']
```

But I want output as below

```
    ['60%', '79.39%', '61.71%']
```

Anybody can tell where I am going wrong and regex to get expected output.

Comment: Well if you are capturing only the first part, what else do you expect to happen ... capture the whole thing then, if you want the whole thing?

Comment: One wonders whatever you were thinking of with the sequence `[0-9]\d?`. Do you know what `\d` matches?

Comment: You get your unexpected result, by the way, because of the capturing group. Which you don't need. Changing it to `(?:..)` fixes your regex (... well it makes it work, but not "better").

Comment: I don't get the downvotes for this question.. OP asked a clear question, gave sample, showed what they'd tried..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the RegEx [`(\d+(\.\d+)?%)`](https://regex101.com/r/YGwQzY/1)

- `\d+` captures 1 or more digits
- `(\.\d+)?` captures a dot and 1 or more digits `0` or `1` time
- `%` captures `%` literally

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/YGwQzY/1)

Comment: The test string may contain values like `.87%`. So you can use `\d*` in that case

Comment: @Gurman What do you mean? OP never said anything about this.

Comment: I just meant that at times people write `.75%` instead of `0.75%`. So for that case we can use [`(\d*(\.\d+)?%)`](https://regex101.com/r/YGwQzY/2). If we use, `\d+` at the beginning, it expects at least 1 digit before the decimal. I know, OP didn't mention this in the requirement. Commented based on my past observations